# Spring AOP: confirming CGLIB proxy behaviour

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop, cglib

While referring to 'Pro Spring 2.5', I came across the following statement (page 193):

> For instance, the CGLIB proxy generates the appropriate bytecode to
>   invoke any unadvised methods directly, dramatically reducing the
>   overhead introduced by the proxy.

I have looked at the Spring source code and tried a few experiments, but could not confirm this statement. What simple program can I write to confirm it?

Answer (score 0):

Use VisualVM and profile the code, or dump the bytecode using BCEL and look through the assembly. For the visualvm route, profile the code, take a snapshot, verifiy the method stack trace.

Comment: to get the stack trace, I did something easier. I created a Throwable in both advised and non advised methods and printed its stack trace. But for both, they were called by 'Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept' which in turn created a 'CglibMethodInvocation' object and called proceed on it. So from a stack trace point, I did not see any difference. Will try the BCEL approach.

Comment: I tried it by using BCEL's 'Repository.lookupClass(clazz)' where clazz is the CGLIB proxy class object. But I got the following exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SyntheticRepository could not load foo.Foo$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$42857850

Comment: I know visualvm can see through Spring AOP proxies (I've had to profile them before), I guess give that a try.